# Sync tiny calendar

Tags: ios, contacts, calendar

I have two iPhones running iOS 12.1.2, each with different Apple IDs. One phone (an iPhone 5S) has complete data for tiny calendar but incomplete contacts. The iPhone 5SE has complete contacts but incomplete calendar data.  I would like them to sync. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If tiny calendar uses the built in calendar accounts like (some?) other third party calendar apps do, you can open Calendars.app and tap "Calendars" at the bottom, and then the "i" in a circle next to a calendar. From there you can share iCloud calendars that you have created.

I'm not sure about contacts. You can share contacts one at a time from the contact, but that doesn't keep them in sync. And I don't see a way to do it more than one at a time.

Comment: Thanks dwightk. I went back into the settings and did my best to list the same email address and google accounts.  The calendar data did expand but they do not sync between IDs.  I am wondering if I should just try to use one ID.  I am guessing just because I stop using an ID it shouldn't evaporate. It will still be out there if I need it. What do you think?

Comment: Yep. One ID would be the easiest. If there’s a reason you want two you might look into family sharing. https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/ I haven’t used it but it says you can share a family calendar. It also might let you sync contacts.